# Can't get table cells to expand evenly

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to get my table to expand each cell evenly but not overlap when condensed. My css is

```
table.basic {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 0px solid black;
  width: 100%;
}
```

and my html is

```
<table class="basic" style="white-space: nowrap">
  <tr>
    <th>Hex</th>
    <th>RGB</th>
    <th>HSL</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="colorhexDIV"></td>
    <td id="colorrgbDIV"></td>
    <td id="colorhslDIV"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

right now they don't overlap but they are not centered
[image]

If I add `table-layout: fixed;` then they are centered but overlap

[image]

I am also trying to avoid wrapping like so

[image]

How do I center it and keep cells from overlapping?

Comment: I created a fiddle of the code you provided and I can not reproduce, could you please prepare a demo?

Comment: @Noctane I added table-layout: fixed to the table.basic class to get them to overlap and be centered. That code exactly doesn't reproduce the problem exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove `white-space: nowrap` from your **HTML**, and then you can use `width: 33%`

```css
table.basic {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 0px solid black;
  width: 100%;
}

th,td {
  width: 33.3%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table class="basic">
  <tr>
    <th>Hex</th>
    <th>RGB</th>
    <th>HSL</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="colorhexDIV">Text</td>
    <td id="colorrgbDIV">Text</td>
    <td id="colorhslDIV">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi ex alias nihil minus labore perspiciatis maiores porro quas eius provident expedita, dolore obcaecati officiis consectetur quidem, animi aperiam exercitationem est.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That worked. I tried that but I guess I made the class wrong or something. Thanks!

Comment: I just noticed you have `style="white-space: nowrap"` in your HTML that is problem. I updated my answer i think that is what you are looking for.

Comment: I still have that in the html and it works fine. I just redid the class for the `td, th` and it worked fine. I had `tr.basic, td.basic` and changed it to `.basictr`

Comment: Ok but if you increase text in cells it won't wrap properly as you can see here https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/287/

Comment: Oh I see what you are saying

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `white-space: nowrap`

Comment: If the table collapses too far then the text wraps and I don't want it to do that since it makes it unreadable. I just want to use the horizontal scrollbar at that point

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that

Comment: I added a picture of what I don't want it to look like. I want it to just go off screen if it's too wide which is what it is doing now. The widest it will ever be will be something like `ff0000 (255, 255, 255) (345, 100%, 100%)`

Comment: I see. Well in that case you can use queries like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/288/, or maybe you should use some other layout and not tables

Comment: But i think this answers your original question

Answer (score 0):

To center the content of the cell use the text-align style.
style="text-align:center;"
The contents of the table datacell will expand depending on whats inside of them try using a div or span and setting it to a fixed size so all the content is the same length.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question or maybe I misunderstood your answer but I am trying to have the cells evenly spaced across the entire width and when I collapse the table keep the cells from overlapping

Answer (score 0):

You can use `table-layout: fixed` which stops the table and it's children from sizing according to their content and set a width to one of the element of the table

Comment: That helps center everything but then when I collapse the table it causes the cells to overlap.